# Clear & Retrieve Previous Data From Access Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm having trouble clearing and getting back the previous records which were stored in my Access (mdb) database after filtering the BindingSource for search purpose. It works fine at startup. But after searching for something. I cannot retrieve my old data back.

Here is my code:

```
Try
    LiqfinalBindingSource.Filter = "(CustomerName LIKE '" & dbnamesearch.Text & "')"

    With DbfinalDataGridView
        .DataSource = LiqfinalBindingSource
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Note: I'm not using a connection string to connect to my database or any other manual procedures.

Comment: `I'm not using connecting string to connect to my database` then how do you expect to connect to the DB?  The empty catch block is a bad idea too

Comment: The non-empty catch block is also a bad idea _while debugging_. Temporarily, remove the catch block entirely while you're debugging a problem (or temporarily rethrow the exception by calling `Throw` inside the catch block).

Comment: @Plutonix, I used the simple Automated Service Based Connection for not knowing much about this things. Only a beginner now.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Didn't quite understood those complex methods for being a total beginner. Is there any way to filter the binding source to retrieve all the Data's back to the datatable?

Comment: `LiqfinalBindingSource.RemoveFilter`

Comment: @LarsTech Dude! You're a life saver!